# Rounded corner for Entry - Xamarin forms UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, customization, xamarin.uwp, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.entry

Is there anything possible to customize the radius of Entry to having a slightly rounded corner?

[image]

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18056/border-radius-and-border-on-entry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use  `Custom Renderer` in xamarin.forms

> in iOS

```
//...
using App11;
using App11.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyiOSEntry))]
namespace App11.iOS
{
  public class MyiOSEntry:EntryRenderer
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;  //set the rounded corner
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 3;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

> in Android

creat a xml file in the folder **Resource->drawable** `edit_text_style.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
   <shape
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
      android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
      android:radius="10dp" />
    <stroke
      android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#3bbdfa" />
   </shape>
</item>
```

in `Custom Renderer`

```
using Android.Support.V4.Content.Res;
using App11;
using App11.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyAndriodEntry))]
namespace App11.Droid
{
 public class MyAndriodEntry:EntryRenderer
 {
   public MyAndriodEntry(Context context):base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            Control.SetBackground(ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.edit_text_style, null) );
        }

    }
  }
}
```

> in UWP

create a folder named Styles and add a new item as type Resource Dictionary and name it Dictionary1.xaml
in Dictionary1.xaml put this code for a rounded Textbox .

in `Custom Renderer`

```
using App11;
using App11.UWP;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyUWPEntry))]
namespace App11.UWP
{
  public class MyUWPEntry:EntryRenderer
  {

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
           Control.Style = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)App11.UWP.App.Current.Resources["StyleRoundedTextBox"];
        }

    }
  }
}
```

how do I changed this style and how do I create this code ? 
It's simple , in msdn.com search for "objectName" default style in uwp then you will find default style for the object you need . change it in the way you want and add it to application resources directly or link it (like what I did here) then load your style in CustomRenderer

for more detail about UWP yo can refer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/284847/#Comment_284847)

> in Forms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App11
{
 public class MyEntry : Entry
 {
    public MyEntry()
    {

    }
 }
}
```

in xxx.cs file

```
Content = new StackLayout
 {
    Children = {
                 new MyEntry {Text = "In Shared Code",}
                },
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows app you can customize an entry using a renderer.

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomEntry, TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomEntry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.BorderThickness = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(1);
        textBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(GetSolidColorBrush("#444444").Color);
        textBox.CornerRadius = new Windows.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius(10);
        this.SetNativeControl(textBox);
    }
    public SolidColorBrush GetSolidColorBrush(string hex)
    {
        hex = hex.Replace("#", string.Empty);
        byte r = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(0, 2), 16));
        byte g = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(2, 2), 16));
        byte b = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(4, 2), 16));

        SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b));
        return myBrush;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Holy shmoley it's not that hard.

Unless I'm missing something, just wrap it in a `Frame` that has `IsClippedToBounds` set to true and then put a corner radius on the frame.

Maybe there's some reason that's not a good solution, I guess, but it's one I use a lot.