# what approach to use a specific component that is only available for iOS or WPF or android in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependencies, custom-renderer

what approach is used to create a specific component that is only available for one platform?
Can I use Custom Renderer or DependencyService or any other approaches is there ?

Comment: Well depends alot on what you are working with be specific so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the UI desinger on a specific control or layout .Such as entry or button.You can use custom renderer.

> Custom renderers provide a powerful approach for customizing the appearance and behavior of Xamarin.Forms controls. They can be used for small styling changes or sophisticated platform-specific layout and behavior customization. This article provides an introduction to custom renderers, and outlines the process for creating a custom renderer.

And you can use  DependencyService if you 
just  want to call some native API .

> DependencyService allows apps to call into platform-specific
>   functionality from shared code. This functionality enables
>   Xamarin.Forms apps to do anything that a native app can do.

And you can also use [Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/).In some cases, all three can help you implement your requirements.

There are some  relevant cases that use one of them to solve the issue.I hope they can  help you better understand their differences and usage, and how to choose them as a solution in specific cases.

[CustomRenderer case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972394/rounded-corner-for-entry-xamarin-forms-uwp/52980814#52980814)

[DependencyService case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197727/net-or-xamarin-internet-availability-check-when-the-wifi-network-has-no-interne/54230085#54230085)

[Effect case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738395/adding-long-press-gesture-recognizer-in-xamarin-forms/53755758#53755758)